# Latexmk says the file is up-to-date, while it's not

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

For some reason the `pdflatexmk` typesetter is sometimes not recognising changes in my file and it returns:

```
Latexmk: All targets (main.pdf) are up-to-date
```

while the target is not up-to-date.
When I type something in `three.tex`, click save and then typeset, sometimes it typesets fine, sometimes it shows the above message.
When the above message is shown I need to type some more text, and try to typeset again. After several tries it will typeset normally.

I've included a stripped down version of my files below:

`main.tex`:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper, hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}                    
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}       
\usepackage{pdfsync}                    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[section]{placeins}                    
\usepackage{parskip}                    
\usepackage{amsmath}                    
\usepackage{natbib}                 
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}          

\includeonly{chapters/three}

\begin{document}
\include{chapters/one}
\include{chapters/two}
\include{chapters/three}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\biblipgraphy{refs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

`three.tex` (located in folder `./chapters`):

```
% !TEX root = ../main.tex
\chapter{Three}
\label{chap:three}

Text, figures and equations
```

I'm using TeXShop 3.23 on Mac OSX 10.8.4. It all worked fine for months with this setup, but now something has changed (no clue what).

**Update:**
I found a file in the main directory named `pdflatex24719.fls` that contained the following:

```
PWD /Users/user/Documents/Dropbox/main
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

I've never seen the file before, so I decided to delete it. After deletion all worked fine again as it should.

**Update 2:**
And the behaviour is back again. Although I have changed the text in `three.tex` `pdflatexmk` still says it's up-to-date.

**Update 3:**
I found out that the `.pdf` is updated. When I open it with Preview.app I see the updated version. However, the TexShop preview window keeps showing the old `.pdf` file.

**Update 4:**
Following the advice of [texenthusiast](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15717/texenthusiast) I created a sample bibliography `refs.bib` and a sample tex file `sample.tex`. The latter looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}
\begin{document}

test citing~\cite{Rom1992}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

While in the folder of the `sample.tex` I ran `latexmk -pdf sample.tex` in the Terminal and checked the pdf file. After I made an edit to the `.tex` file I ran the command again. The change was reflected in the pdf file.

Comment: what's your `latexmk -v` version

Comment: `Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 2 July 2013, version: 4.37.
`

Comment: Are you having Two versions(2012 & 2013) side by side of TeX distro on Mac ? Did you try terminal approach deleting all .aux files

Comment: I only have the 2012 TeX distro. I deleted all the `.aux` files, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you `install latest latexmk` version separately  outside TeX distro ? because 2012 TeX distro would have it

Comment: Yes, I think I did (99% sure).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10209/discussion-between-texenthusiast-and-bart-arondson)

Comment: So I suppose latexmk is working , only TeXshop viewer might need to update the new pdf(after edit).

Comment: For what it's worth, I am unable to reproduce the problem with the same source files and TeXShop 2.47 under TeXLive 2013 on OS-X 10.6.8, and the current version of `latexmk`.

Comment: If Aubrey Blumsohn solution helped, you should switch your pdf viewer to one that will update with each compile.  On Linux, I use Okular, but for Mac, I believe Skim will do that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens to me frequently. When it does, the cause is always the same. I compile to pdf, but while I have the existing pdf from the last compile open in Acrobat Reader. The compile completes but cannot write to the pdf. If I then recompile I get your error (i.e pdf is not up to date, but the compiler says it is).

The solution is to delete the pdf before re-compiling the second time.

Comment: I just ran into this issue, but the PDF appears to update just fine in `evince`. It seems `latexmk` just isn't updating the filetime. Adding `touch $@` to the end of my rule fixes it.

Comment: @jozxqk: If the pdf-file is not regenerated, the timestamp (filetime) of the file of course does not change. If the pdf-file is regenerated, the timestamp changes. So does latexmk. So I do not really understand your comment. I am surprised that `touch $@` helps which shouldn't. See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/27357/can-i-make-acrobat-reader-reload-a-changed-pdf.

Comment: For me, just closing the .pdf without deleting it, solves the problem

Answer (score 9):

An option could be to add the `-g` flag when using `latexmk:`

`latexmk -pdf -g main.tex`

From the `latexmk`[documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.txt) for `-g`

> Force latexmk to process document fully, even  under  situations
>                 where  latexmk  would  normally  decide  that  no changes in the
>                 source files have occurred since the previous run.

---

#### With GNU make

As a side note, this may be of help when mixing GNU `make` and `latexmk`. If the `latexmk` command is executed by `make,` there *must* have been a change in the prerequisites of `main.pdf.` `latexmk` does not seem to always pick this up and returns `All targets (main.pdf) are up-to-date.` With `-g`, however, compilation is enforced at least once.

In the case of `make,` adding the option `-use-make`

`latexmk -pdf -g -use-make main.tex`

may also be worthwhile, as it causes `latexmk` to call `make` to create whatever it was missing as input.

For other situations, without `make,` it probably depends on wether you are willing to incur the cost of at least one compilation run, even in cases where it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

#### `-recorder`

Another noteworthy point is that the option `-recorder` should be enabled.

The `.fls` file of the OP contains only two `INPUT` lines which indicate that the `-recorder` option is not enabled.  If `-recorder` is enabled, all input files such as `chapters/one`, the bib file and more will be added and latexmk can detect changes here:

`man latexmk` (Version 4.52c) says

```
-recorder
 Give the -recorder option with latex and pdflatex.  In (most) modern versions of these 
 programs, this results in  a file of extension .fls containing a list of the files that
 these programs have read and written.  Latexmk will then use this file to improve its
 detection of source files and generated files after a run of latex or pdflatex.  This
 is the default setting of latexmk, unless overridden in an initialization file.

 For further information, see the documentation for the $recorder configuration variable.
```