# Latexmk says "all targets are up-to-date" though bib file has been changed

Tags: biblatex, biber, latexmk

When I change something in my bib file, click save and run Latexmk command, it always says:

> Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80.
> Latexmk: Nothing to do for './main.tex'.
> Latexmk: All targets (main.pdf) are up-to-date

I'm using biblatex with biber backend. I want Latexmk to detect changes in bib files. I've tried to add -recorder` flag for Latexmk as suggested in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129056/latexmk-says-the-file-is-up-to-date-while-its-not) but it doesn't work.

Also I've checked main.fls and can't find my bib file. Only files like main.bbl and main.bcf show up there. I think this may indicate Latexmk is not tracking the bib file, but why?

---

### Edit

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Hyper-V virtual machine, if it matters). `tex --version` shows

> TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023)

and I'm compiling using the command `latexmk -xelatex main.tex`.

---

### Edit 2

In the file main.fdb_latexmk, following `["biber`, there are:

> ["biber main"] 1701360730 "main.bcf" "main.bbl" "main" 1701360782 0
> "main.bcf" 1701360782 107749 d415e9cf25de5307100d1c0ac845400a "xelatex"
> (generated)
> "main.bbl"
> "main.blg"
> (rewritten before read)

bib files are not contained in these lines. Also bib files are not shown after running `latexmk -dependents -xelatex`.

Here's the example I'm working on:

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```
% refs.bib
@article{worldHello,
  title = {Hello},
  author = {World},
}
```

Comment: You might want to also list which operating system you are on. Im on Linux and here latexmk recompiles just fine whenever I change a bib file tht my project depends on.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for reply! I've edited the question.

Comment: "Also I've checked main.fls"  that file just lists files input by latex (which never reads a `.bib` file)

Comment: No issues for my Ubuntu 22.04 with upstream TeXLive 2023. latexmk recompiles if I change somehing in the bib file.

Comment: Like @daleif, I find that latexmk reruns biber if the bib file changes.  Some possibilities (a) You've got more than one bib file of the same name; you edited one of them, but biber used a different one. (b) You've set `$bibtex_use` to 0 in a latexmkrc file, which prohibits the running of bibtex and biber. (c) You changed the bib file only by changing its time stamp, e.g., by applying `touch` to it, but made no change in the contents of the file.

Comment: A diagnostic: Look at the file main.fdb_latexmk, which contains latexmk's information about dependencies.  It should contain a line starting `["biber `, followed by lines showing what files biber read, including the bib file(s).  Is that the case?  You can also run `latexmk -dependents`; does the output include the name of the bibfile(s)?

Comment: @JohnCollins Thank you very much for analysing the problem and providing the diagnostic. I've added the result of diagnostic to the question. To clarify, I'm pretty sure I edited the bib file specified in main.tex, and I changed the file by adding entries. Also I don't remember changing any latexmkrc files.

Comment: I see the problem: You've specified the bib file by using the `\bibliography` macro instead of `\addbibresource`.  (Note that the biblatex documentation deprecates `\bibliography`.)  That triggers a subtle bug in the dependency detection by latexmk, which I'll need to correct.  For now, change`\bibliography` to `\addbibresource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the document, the command `\bibliography{refs.bib}` was used to specify the .bib file instead of `\addbibresource{refs.bib}`.  In this situation, latexmk (up to its current version 4.81) does not detect the dependency.  Note that the biblatex documentation deprecates `\bibliography`.

The easiest solution is just to switch to using `\addbibresource`.

The next release of latexmk (probably 4.82) will correct this bug (and a number of other problems with the use of biblatex and biber).